# After setting the yAxis max value, some datalabels are not showing

Tags: highcharts

I am making a bar chart graph, but after adding a yAxis max, some data labels are not visible anymore.

[JSFiddle with my code](https://jsfiddle.net/dx8fo4jm/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    alignTicks:false  
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        align: 'right',
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        x: -10
      },
      pointPadding: 0.15,
      groupPadding: 0
    }
  },
  yAxis:{max:150},
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set `inside: true` in your `datalabels` options.

[See updated jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/6g3sLzr4/)

[See documentation about it here](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.inside)